# Serverless Error occurred: ApiGatewayResourcePatientsetPidVar - A sibling ({id}) of this resource already

Tags: aws-lambda, parameters, serverless

I'm new to Lambda Computing and AWS. I'm trying to set up a REST API Service with Lambda. I have three different functions defined in my `serverless.yml` file from my handler something like this:

```
functions:
  users:
    handler: handler.users
    events:
      - http:
          path: users
          method: get
          cors: true
          integration: lambda
  stats:
    handler: handler.Stats
    events:
      - http:
          path: users/{id}/stats
          method: get
          cors: true
          integration: lambda
  contribution:
    handler: handler.contribution
    events:
      - http:
          path: patientset/{pid}/contribution
          method: get
          cors: true
          integration: lambda
```

When I deploy the same, it throws me an error:

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
 
An error occurred: ApiGatewayResourcePatientsetPidVar - A sibling ({id}) of this resource already has a variable path part -- only one is allowed (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: f4047858-b52d-4721-b0a2-069a59254e6b; Proxy: null).
```

So to test it, I change the path for the function `contribution` from `patientset/{pid}/contribution` to `patientset/{id}/contribution`, the deployment is successful.

But this is what I don't require. I need to define the proper name convention for each function to help recognize what kind of `id` a function is expecting as it's path parameter.

I also tried resolving the same with some suggestions around as found [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3785), but this also didn't help. If anyone can help provide any solution for the same & this explains this weird behavior from serverless, highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if path is not repeated for any of handlers
2. Comment the section causing issue and deploy once.
   Then uncomment then section, redeploy.
   Its a known bug in serverless with AWS
   I faced same issue got resolved with this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a long standing AWS issue where changing the endpoint variable causes an issue

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3785